# Keep Getting Bad Request from HTTP.request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, bad-request

I just installed Node.js and perhaps I'm missing something but I'm trying a simple http.request and get nothing but 400 responses.  I've tried several hosts with no luck. I installed Node from their site, this didn't work, so I uninstalled and installed via Homebrew and get the same output of "400". I'm specifically wondering if there's something I need to change on my Mac to allow Node to send requests.

OSX 10.8.4
Node 0.10.13
Homebrew 0.9.4

```
var http = require("http");

var req = http.request({
    host: "http://google.com"
}, function(res){
    if (res.statusCode === 200) console.log(res);
    else console.log(res.statusCode);
});

req.on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
});

req.end();
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The http:// in your host is confusing things.  Try switching it to "www.google.com".  It's an http request, no need to repeat yourself :)

Comment: Yep, that was it! Must have gotten that from a bad example. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JoshR, You should mark this as the accepted answer (by clicking the green checkmark) if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking the `http://` out of your `host` parameter? I often use the [`url`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) utility for things like this. It'll automatically parse a url into the correct parts to pass to `http.request`.

```
var url = require('url'),
    link = url.parse('http://www.google.com/');

var req = http.request({
    host: link.hostname,
    path: link.path,
    port: link.port
}, function(res){
    if (res.statusCode === 200) console.log(res);
    else console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Also, I'd make sure to catch the error event as well in case that is throwing an error. From the docs:

```
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
```

If you just need a `GET` response you can also use [`http.get`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) instead. From the docs:

```
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: I'm late to the party but the 'url' utility saved me a lot of hassle, even though I already knew to remove the 'http://' bit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a missing leading slash in `path` parameter

E.g., this works:

```js
http.request({
    host: 'example.com',
    path: '/foo/bar.html',
}, (res) => {...});
```

But this DOESN'T WORK (getting Error 400):

```js
http.request({
    host: 'example.com',
    path: 'foo/bar.html',
}, (res) => {...});
```