# How to send http request to google map api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, httprequest, bad-request

This is the request I'm making in my node.js app:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
    path: '/maps/api/geocode/json',
    method: 'GET',
    useQuerystring: true,
    qs: 'address=' + "1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA" + "&key=[redacted in stack overflow post]"
};

var req = https.request(options, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    //Uncomment the code below when you start getting valid responses
    //response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    //    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    //});
});
console.log(req);
req.end();
```

But the response comes back with statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad Request'. The full response can be found below.

I don't see my query string in either the request or the response, that seems concerning to me. I have tried removing `useQuerystring: true,` from options, this seems to have no effect. I have also tried adding www. in front of maps.googleapis.com, which I knew wouldn't work and confirmed that.

I'm making a successful request with Postman that looks like this:
`GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=[redacted in stack overflow post]`

**How can I make a request that will get a successful response in Node using the https module?**

This is the output from `console.log(req)`:

```
ClientRequest {
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { response: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     socket: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onSocket] } },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [],
  outputEncodings: [],
  outputCallbacks: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  upgrading: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedHeader: {},
  _contentLength: null,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: false,
  _headerSent: false,
  socket: null,
  connection: null,
  _header: null,
  _headers: { host: 'maps.googleapis.com' },
  _headerNames: { host: 'Host' },
  _onPendingData: null,
  agent: 
   Agent {
     domain: null,
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     defaultPort: 443,
     protocol: 'https:',
     options: { path: null },
     requests: {},
     sockets: { 'maps.googleapis.com:443::::::::': [Object] },
     freeSockets: {},
     keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
     keepAlive: false,
     maxSockets: Infinity,
     maxFreeSockets: 256,
     maxCachedSessions: 100,
     _sessionCache: { map: {}, list: [] } },
  socketPath: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/maps/api/geocode/json',
  _ended: false }
```

This is the output from `console.log(res)`:

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function: responseOnEnd] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions: 
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: false,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
        data: [Function: socketOnData] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TLSWrap {
        bytesRead: 608,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        _parent: [Object],
        _parentWrap: undefined,
        _secureContext: [Object],
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        writeQueueSize: 1,
        onhandshakestart: [Function],
        onhandshakedone: [Function],
        onocspresponse: [Function],
        onerror: [Function] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 85,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: 
      TLSWrap {
        bytesRead: 608,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        _parent: [Object],
        _parentWrap: undefined,
        _secureContext: [Object],
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        writeQueueSize: 1,
        onhandshakestart: [Function],
        onhandshakedone: [Function],
        onocspresponse: [Function],
        onerror: [Function] },
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': null,
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: [Object],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /maps/api/geocode/json HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/maps/api/geocode/json',
        _ended: false,
        parser: [Object],
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true },
  connection: 
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions: 
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: false,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
        data: [Function: socketOnData] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TLSWrap {
        bytesRead: 608,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        _parent: [Object],
        _parentWrap: undefined,
        _secureContext: [Object],
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        writeQueueSize: 1,
        onhandshakestart: [Function],
        onhandshakedone: [Function],
        onocspresponse: [Function],
        onerror: [Function] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 85,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: 
      TLSWrap {
        bytesRead: 608,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        _parent: [Object],
        _parentWrap: undefined,
        _secureContext: [Object],
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        writeQueueSize: 1,
        onhandshakestart: [Function],
        onhandshakedone: [Function],
        onocspresponse: [Function],
        onerror: [Function] },
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': null,
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: [Object],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /maps/api/geocode/json HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/maps/api/geocode/json',
        _ended: false,
        parser: [Object],
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     date: 'Sat, 20 May 2017 15:12:32 GMT',
     pragma: 'no-cache',
     expires: 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
     'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
     server: 'mafe',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"',
     'accept-ranges': 'none',
     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
     connection: 'close' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'Content-Type',
     'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     'Date',
     'Sat, 20 May 2017 15:12:32 GMT',
     'Pragma',
     'no-cache',
     'Expires',
     'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
     'Cache-Control',
     'no-cache, must-revalidate',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
     '*',
     'Server',
     'mafe',
     'X-XSS-Protection',
     '1; mode=block',
     'X-Frame-Options',
     'SAMEORIGIN',
     'Alt-Svc',
     'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"',
     'Accept-Ranges',
     'none',
     'Vary',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'Connection',
     'close' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
  client: 
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions: 
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: false,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
        data: [Function: socketOnData] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TLSWrap {
        bytesRead: 608,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        _parent: [Object],
        _parentWrap: undefined,
        _secureContext: [Object],
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        writeQueueSize: 1,
        onhandshakestart: [Function],
        onhandshakedone: [Function],
        onocspresponse: [Function],
        onerror: [Function] },
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 85,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: 
      TLSWrap {
        bytesRead: 608,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: -1,
        _parent: [Object],
        _parentWrap: undefined,
        _secureContext: [Object],
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        writeQueueSize: 1,
        onhandshakestart: [Function],
        onhandshakedone: [Function],
        onocspresponse: [Function],
        onerror: [Function] },
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': null,
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: [Object],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /maps/api/geocode/json HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/maps/api/geocode/json',
        _ended: false,
        parser: [Object],
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  req: 
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events: { prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 85,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: [Object],
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     connection: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 85,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: [Object],
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     _header: 'GET /maps/api/geocode/json HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: maps.googleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _headers: { host: 'maps.googleapis.com' },
     _headerNames: { host: 'Host' },
     _onPendingData: null,
     agent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/maps/api/geocode/json',
     _ended: false,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': null,
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: false,
        socket: [Object],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient] },
     res: [Circular] } }
```

Note: I have read [Keep Getting Bad Request from HTTP.request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690402/keep-getting-bad-request-from-http-request-in-node-js) and that is not my problem. I specifically should not include a www. in front of maps.googleapis.com

For those of you reading this later on, once you've received a good response, you might want to read this: [Where is body in a nodejs http.get response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968448/where-is-body-in-a-nodejs-http-get-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to specify the queryString in the URL itself: `path:'/maps/api/geocode/json' + '?' + <QueryString>`

Alernatively, you could consider using the 'requestify' module. It can be installed via '**npm**'.

The **source code** can be found at :-
https://github.com/ranm8/requestify

Thus, your code would look something like :-

```
var requestify = require('requestify'); 
requestify.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=<API_KEY>').then(function(response) {

    // Get the response body
    response.getBody();
});
```

**IMP**: Remember to replace your own API_KEY in the URL without the angular brackets.

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should have specified that I intend to use the https module and want to avoid another dependency.

Comment: @Glen, could you please look in the "**Networks**" tab in the Chrome "**Developer Console**" and see at what URL the HTTP request is being fired.

Also, you might be missing a '**?**' at the end of the '**path**' field.

Comment: Another thing, you can try is to specify the queryString in the URL itself, i.e. :-
**path**:'/maps/api/geocode/json' + '?' + <QueryString>

Comment: I'm making the call from my server, it's not client side so I don't have access to the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Adjusting the request options to include the query string in the path results in a good response (status 200). Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help..:)
Could you please mark my answer as 'accepted', in order to help future users who might face this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the answer so that it's clear that the solution is what you described in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have now approved it. 
Could you please mark it as 'accepted' now.
Thanks.